# Android smooth image animation

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

I am working on image animation. I have 200 transparent png images which I am trying to show one by one over a background image.

Can you tell me the best way to do it. The image should change in such a way that it should appear that a cartoon is running.

If you can tell me in steps, it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at animation frames: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation-list to play them frame by frame
http://app-solut.com/blog/2011/05/playing-animations-in-android/

or create a GIF and play it
http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Gif is more lightweigt, but it gave me trouble once when played on some MDPI screen devices, where I had a single Gif file in the drawable-hdpi folder. So give it a try first..